# Getting data from multiple tables in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So far I am using it like below to get data from multiple tables:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get_data_on_login(@RequestParam(value="username") String username) throws Exception {
    List<TopicBean> topics = topicService.findAllTopics();
    UserInfo role = userInfoService.findRoleByUsername(username);
    return new ResponseEntity(new LoginDataBean( topics, role.getRole(), role.getUserImage()),  HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

but as the requirement to get data from more number of table increases, its getting complicated.

What I am looking for is to get data like this but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<LoginDataBean, Long>{

    List<LoginDataBean> SearchByTopicBeanAndCommentBeanAndCommentLikes(TopicBean topicBean, CommentBean commentBean, CommentLikes commentLikes);

}
```

I have LoginDataBean like this:

```
public class LoginDataBean {

    @Autowired
    private final List<TopicBean> topics;

    private String userImage;

    private String role;

    public LoginDataBean(List<TopicBean> topics, String role, String userImage){
        this.topics = topics;
        this.role = role;
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getRole(){
        return role;
    }

    public String userImage(){
        return userImage;
    }

    public List<TopicBean> getTopics() {
        return topics;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from multiple tables based on entities in spring jpa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037275/get-data-from-multiple-tables-based-on-entities-in-spring-jpa)