# Get data from multiple tables based on entities in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities like below:

Comments:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class CommentBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private long commentId;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
}
```

Topics:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "dayPosted")
    private String dayPosted;
}
```

Likes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_likes")
public class CommentLikes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentLikes")
    private String commentLikes;

    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private long commentId;
}
```

I want to get all data from three tables/entities on request:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get_data_on_login()) throws Exception {

}
```

How do I achieve this? I have seen examples using @query and some examples using `searchByAnd...` but Its more confusing which approach to follow.

**Update:**

Tried using @JoinColumn to map tables to get the data using `bean.findAll()` however, I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at seconds47.Application.main(Application.java:24) [classes/:?]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: seconds47.beans.CommentBean column: topicId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 more
```

Update code:

Topic Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "dayPosted")
    private String dayPosted;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="topicBean")
    private List<CommentBean> commentBeans;
}
```

commentBean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class CommentBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private long commentId;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;

    @Column(name = "comments")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "commentDate")
    private String commentDate;

    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="topicId")
    private TopicBean topicBean;
}
```

Repositories:

comment Likes Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CommentLikeRepository extends JpaRepository<CommentLikes, Long>{

    CommentLikes findByCommentId(long commentId);
}
```

comment reply Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CommentReplyRepository extends JpaRepository<CommentReply, Long> {

    CommentReply findByReplyId(String replyId);

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByReplyId(String replyId);

}
```

comment Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<CommentBean, Long>{
    List<CommentBean> findByTopicId(String topicId);
    CommentBean findByCommentId(long commentId);

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByCommentId(long deleteId);
}
```

Topic Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<TopicBean, Long> {
    TopicBean findByTopicId(String topicId);

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByTopicId(String topicId);

    List<TopicBean> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

user info repo:

```
@Repository
public interface UserInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInfo, Long>{

    UserInfo findByUsername(String username);

    UserInfo findRoleByUsername(String username);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your tags include **spring-boot** and **spring-jpa**.
I assume you can use **spring data repositories**

The entities posted are not associated in any way. Therefore, the entities must be associated in order to retrieve all the data with one repository
The modified version of entities look like this:

comments table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class CommentBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private long commentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="topicId")
    private TopicBean topicBean;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="commentBean")
    private List<CommentLikes> commentLikesList;
}
```

topics table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "dayPosted")
    private String dayPosted;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="topicBean")
    private List<CommentBean> commentBeans;
}
```

comment_likes table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_likes")
public class CommentLikes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "commentLikes")
    private String commentLikes;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="commentId")
    private CommentBean commentBean;
}
```

Note that the above rewrite is based on the most sensible guess I can make according to the original entities.

Now the three entities are properly associated.
You can just use TopicBean repository to retrieve all the TopicBeans and the other two will be retrieved as well.
`topicBeanRepo.findAll()`

Comment: This is only one possible solution. Your question does not say only one repository is desired and there is no repository of yours posted, so I guess you need a working example. From the tables you posted, there is no way to do it with only one repository because the tables are not associated in any way.

Comment: `topicBeanRepo.findAll()` will return a list in this case?

Comment: @kittu Like my previous answer, the `CommentBean` Entity does not need a `topicId` field. `@JoinColumn(name="topicId") private TopicBean topicBean` already **associates** them. The entity classes I posted are based on my guess of what you intended. In my opinion, you don't even need `topicId` in `TopicBean field unless your business logic really requires a second identity column other than the `@ID id`. You can make the foriegn key directly refer to the primary key `id`. I kindly recommend that you grab a JPA book and learn the basics. That's how I learned it and it worked very well.